# external hard drive volumn corrupted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I'm using seagate external hard drive. 
actually it failed to mount

> ```
> jake@jake-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
> Mounting volume... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
> highest_vcn = 0xb8ba3, last_vcn - 1 = 0xb8b9f
> Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
> FAILED
> Attempting to correct errors... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
> highest_vcn = 0xb8ba3, last_vcn - 1 = 0xb8b9f
> Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
> FAILED
> Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
> Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
> Unrecoverable error
> Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
> ```

if I format it is it going to be solved? 
or is there any way to solve it or save the datas?

 what is the main problem here and how to slove it?

Comment: The MFT table is destroyed. Try `chkdsk` as advised. If this doesn't work, you will need to rescue the data. Formatting will destroy everything.

Comment: You need Windows to run `chkdsk`.